# I want to add product description image in product detail page but don't know how. Can you help me?

Tags: product-images, product-view, product-detail-page, image-preview, product-description

I want to add product description image in product detail page but don't know how. Can you help me?
It looks like this:

[image]

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the wording of the question you simply want to add images to the description of a product using the Magento 2 Admin and not with an import from a PIM, CSV import, or by using code customization.

You find the product description when you edit a product under "Content".
You might first have to uncollapse the section on the edit product page.
[image: Product Content on Edit Product page]

### WYSIWYG Editor

When the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor is used, you can insert an image with the `Insert/Add image` tool in the toolbar of the editor.
[image: TinyMCE image tool]

### PageBuilder

If you use a current version of Magento (or an older commerce version) you might have the PageBuilder as the editor for your product description.
To modify the description of a product, click on "Edit with PageBuilder" and the PageBuilder will open. Be sure to first add an element (like row) from the "Layout" section if there are no elements right now in the description.

Now there are three common ways how images can be added:

**1. Image Content-Type**

Drag and drop an image content type from the sidebar to the content area. You can then click on "Upload image" or "Select from Gallery" to select an image to show.
[image: Image Content Type]

**2. Text Content-Type**

When using a simple text content type, you will have the WYSIWYG editor as described under *WYSIWIG Editor* above.
[image: Text Content-Type]

**3. HTML Coded Content-Type**

When using the HTML code content type, there is a dedicated "Insert image" button when you open "Edit HTML code" that allows you to add images. This will add a prefilled `<img>`-tag to your HTML code.

[image: HTML Code Content Type]

Comment: thank you! but that's not what i meant. I want to add a product description photo or video to the right side of the detail page. I want to put two images "Image Description" and "Image Description 2" like below. Is there a way to automatically retrieve all products?

Answer (score 0):

I want to put two images "Image Description" and "Image Description 2" like below.

[image]

Is there a way to automatically retrieve all products?